# how do i format the value shown in a d3 graph

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to change the formatting on the value shown on top of the bar graph in a nvd3 discrete bar graph. I believe I am doing something wrong, I have no idea.

Here is the js fiddle for the graph
http://jsfiddle.net/looneydoodle/PdpRq/

Here is the code

```
var basicformat = d3.format(',f');
d3graph.selectAll('g.nv-bar text').each(function(d,i){
  this.text(basicformat(this.value));
});
```

**EDIT:**

Figured out how to do it, although it might be a bad way to do it. 
Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/looneydoodle/PdpRq/2/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the discreteBarChart has a `valueFormat()` method. You can sorta see it defined in the [nvd3 source on line 232.](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/discreteBarChart.js)

So, to set a format other than the default that you're seeing, all you need is:

```
chart.valueFormat(d3.format('f'))// Or whatever format you'd like
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrUSj/)

Comment: thanks @meetamit! any idea how i can add another x axis so i can show percent values for each bar?

Comment: @looneydoodle NP. Not sure exactly what's the right way to do it, or that using another x axis is the best approach. But here's one way I can think of: http://jsfiddle.net/mrUSj/1/. Works ok if the chart is not too narrow.

Comment: I think I have to add another graph below it, i dont seem to be able to add another x axis.